# How i extract m3u8 of this link by regex?

Tags: php, regex

How i extract m3u8 of this link by regex ?

http://tvplayerlatino.com/envivo/ver/FoxSports/

I want The result of extract to be similar this :
http://live.tvplayerlatino.com/usuarios/src1/FoxSports/web/playlist.m3u8?BGD0ZwL5BQAsZGD5AQLjAGpmBD==

when we check the source code of this link there is :

```
<video id="player" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" autoplay controls preload="auto" width="640" height="360" data-setup='{}'>
                <source src="http://live.tvplayerlatino.com/usuarios/src1/FoxSports/web/playlist.m3u8?BGD0ZwL5BQAsZGD5AQLjAGpmBD==" type='application/x-mpegURL'>
            </video>
```

This is my code but it doesn't extract m3u8 !!!

which part should change ?!

Answer (score 2):

Make the `.*` non-greedy (`.*?`) and remove the equal sign (a Base64-encoded value does not necessarily end with `=` or `==` - it's just a filler). The regex you need is:

```
(http.*?[^&">]+)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/XlqWgS/1

However, the document you're referencing is full of non-m3u8 links. To grab only m3u8 files put a check against it in the regex:

```
(http.*?\.m3u8[^&">]+)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/XlqWgS/2

Comment: I suppose, "doesn't work" mean the regex grabs links like `https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video.js` as well, doesn't it?

Comment: No , your regex code is wrong ,  
it gives " syntax error , unexpected ']' "

Comment: I provided a pure regex. When used in PHP, the `"` should be escaped. Alternatively you may use a single-quoted string: `preg_match('/(http.*?[^&">]+)/', $input, $matches);`

Comment: Now its the same as before , with your regex code and my regex code the result of extract is the same , both is : https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arsenal

Comment: The document at https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arsenal apparently does not contain any text similar to the one provided in the OP as sample imput. Please clarify your requirements.

Comment: everything is clear , i written above I want The result of extract to be similar this : http://live.tvplayerlatino.com/usuarios/src1/FoxSports/web/playlist.m3u8?BGD0ZwL5BQAsZGD5AQLjAGpmBD==

Comment: That's why I asked if the regex grabs too much. Please check out the updated answer.

Comment: now the regex answer is :  fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arsenal

Comment: while i need the regex answer to be : http://live.tvplayerlatino.com/usuarios/src1/FoxSports/web/playlist.m3u8?BGD0ZwL5BQAsZGD5AQLjAGpmBD==

Comment: Could you please paste your input string into the "Test string" box of the https://regex101.com/r/XlqWgS/2 form, save it and post the updated link to me?

Answer (score 0):

It is advised to use DOM for this type of action instead of regex. Take a look at [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) or [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php).